# How to stop multiple select options jumping to top of list on click in chrome?

Tags: html, google-chrome

My HTML table is simple. When I click on an option thats visible in the select box, it selects fine however, when I click on an option thats not visible / out of view, the list of options simply scrolls to the top and I get nowhere. The option wont mark as selected even though its highlighted.

This only seems to be a problem with Chrome though as it works fine in FF.

```
<select class="propertytype" multiple>                  
    <option value="Villa">Villa</option>        
    <option value="Hotel">Hotel</option>                    
    <option value="HotelVillas">Hotel Villas</option>   
    <option value="Apartment">Apartment</option>        
    <option value="Private">Private</option>    
    <option value="Villa&ApartmentSales">Villa & Apartment Sales</option>   
    <option value="NewDevelopments">New Developments</option>   
</select>
```